# calling pytest function from another

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have two test pytest one read a value "nb" depending on a number and depending on that value "nb" the second test will create a set of test made of lists with the length=nb
I want the second test to iterate on different list for each value on the first test

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("v",[498,509,690,700])
def test_all(v):
    nb=read_value(v)
    assert nb>0, 'no'

@pytest.mark.parametrize("l", [[randint(0, 900)*-1 for _ in range(nb)]for _ in range(3)])
def test_pred(l):
    print("here")
    assert (np.array(func_to_test(l))>0).all(),'no'
```

i just dont get how to call the second test from the first for each value

Comment: Tests are independent and called by pytest, you cannot call one from the other. You can either add the first `parametrize` mark to the second test additionally (and probably also merge the first test into the second), or you can write a parametrized fixture that provides these values.

Comment: random is also probably not a good idea to use in a test.  imagine if only one of those values caused an error and 99.9% of the time the test passed (but mysteriously sometimes failed!)